# search suggestions not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a search suggestion code that I have took from one of the websites that I have designed before. I copied the full code to my new site but know the search suggestions does not work for some reason!

Please look at the my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--search suggestions-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) 
{
$('#suggestions').hide();
}
else
{
$.post("suggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
if(data.length > 0) {
$('#suggestions').show();
$('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
}
});
}
} 
function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
function outoffocus() {
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

My PHP :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['inputString']))
{ 
  $inputString = safe($_POST['inputString']);
  if(mb_strlen($inputString) > 0)
  {
     $query = $db->query("SELECT title FROM table WHERE title LIKE '$inputString%' LIMIT 5");
     if($db->num_rows($query) > 0) 
     {
        while($result = $db->fetch_array($query))
        {
           echo "<li onClick=\"fill('".$result['title']."');\"><a href='".$config['site_dir']."/".$result['title']."/'>".$result['title']."</a></li>";
        }
     }
     else
     {
        echo "NOTHING HERE GO AWAY";
     }
  } 
}
?>
```

I have tested both the PHP file and the SQL STATMENT. and both of them seems to work.

I think the problems lays in HTML AND JQUERY

HERE is my HTML

```
<form id="search" action="{$url}/search.php" method="get"> 
<input type="text" name="search" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="outoffocus()" onfocus="lookup(this.value);"/>
<input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" >
 <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Two things that you should know before you answer : 
I have a file that is linked to the suggest.php to connect to sql.. so that should not be a problem.
the query that I put there is not exactly the same query that I have in my original file, So I can qurntee you that the problem is not in MYSQL.. it is somewhere in the code that I have given.

Comment: I giving a string to `data` directly instead of you getting it through $.post()  , then the other code works fine. So I think there must be some error during the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing following functions:

```
function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
function outoffocus() {
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

to

```
function fill(thisValue) {
  $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#suggestions').hide(); }, 200);
}
function outoffocus() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#suggestions').hide();}, 200);
}
```

Comment: the results are not showing ! I did not reach the point where I can fill the input with the results..
I do not know why the suggestions are not showing!

Comment: @shnisaka try console.log( data ); in your post callback function and check if you actually get the expected data from POST request..